# How i can restrict the number of rows i can insert into table to just one in Mysql server?

Tags: mysql, sql, request, prestashop

I want put a restriction on my table in Mysql database, to let insert just one row, without using triggers.

Comment: What is the reason of such a strange restriction? It looks like XY-problem, so probably you're solving your initial problem in totally wrong way that brings you to this restriction. Anyway, you can write stored procedure which will insert exactly one row according to parameters supplied, and grant your users permission to execute this procedure but deny from direct inserts to table.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real way to restrict the number of inserts into a table, if a user has the right to insert rows into a table. What you can do is to create a table, insert a single record into it, then revoke insert and delete access from all users (well, perhaps not from the root account), but retain the update right for all users. This way the users can update (change) the record, but cannot insert a new one or delete the existing one.

However, pls note that this requirement should rather be enforced on application, and not on a database level.